# Express 404 error message instead of routing to index.jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

for some reason I am getting a 404 error message instead of my index.jade content fed into my index page. I don't know what I am doing wrong here but this getting boring.

Here's my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render('index.jade', {title: 'index'});
});


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here's my index.js

```
/* GET home page. */
exports.index = function(req, res){
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `routes.index` instead of just `routes` in your `app.use('/', ..)` call?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ended up solving this problem by upgrading to express 4 from express 3. Now it works fine. :)